# Does/Can StringTemplate support Iterable

Tags: stringtemplate-4

I would like to iterate over a collection of data stored in an arbitrary data structure. The only interface I have is Iterable. Is this possible with StringTemplate?

```
<source:{e|e.stuff}>



class Source<HasStuff> implements Iterable<HasStuff> {
   // Implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current release (4.0.7) supports `Iterator`, but not `Iterable`. For details, see the following method, which returns an `Iterator` for use in the mapping operation.

https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/4.0.7/src/org/stringtemplate/v4/Interpreter.java#L1112-L1132